# CSS Compatibily Cross-Browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I'm a web designer and I have a doubt.When I create a site, for styling it I use CSS, but the problem is that the browser understand the CSS n different methods. I mean, if I put a rule in css like `mydiv { margin-left: 20px; }` in firefox I will see it with 5% distant from left. But if I open the site in Chrome I will see it more than 5% distance from left. And I can understand, because there's not the same graphic engine to use. My question is: Is there any method in CSS to maintain the same disntace, width, height and other, in firefox and chrome ( because there are the most used browser) ? I've heard about a -moz-document-url, that say that all rules aplies there will be applied only for Firefox. It is right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this reset :

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
```

**NOTE**

> mydiv { margin-left: 20px; } doesn't exist in css mybe you mean #mydiv
>   { margin-left: 20px; } or .mydiv { margin-left: 20px; }

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Normalize.css makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.